# Excel VBA monthly Timekeeping

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a shared Excel timesheet to be used by around 30 employees for their daily timekeeping.

This timekeeping sheet will record the employees' daily timestamp for their:

```
Start of Pre-shift OverTime, End of Pre-shift Overtime,
Time-In, Time-Out, 
Start of 1st break, End of 1st break, 
Start of Lunch, End of Lunch, 
Start of 2nd break, End of 2nd break, 
Start of Post-shift OverTime, End of Post-shift Overtime, Etc.
```

I created a form interface where a specific employee could tick a `CheckBox` to record his/her timestamp for:

Time-In, Time-Out, Start of 1st break, End of 1st break, and so on.. The timestamp is then forwarded to a table in Sheet2 which captures all of the timestamps of that employee for the day.

**My problem is**: when the employee comes back to work the next day, all of the timestamps for the previous day gets overwritten by the timestamps for the present day.

An expert gave me a sample code but the data in the "time storage" sheet doesn't seem to appear horizontally in one single row. Instead, it appears in a downward diagonal pattern.

If you could help me in any way, it will be much appreciated.

Below is the sample code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rngC As Range
    Dim lngR As Long
    Dim shtS As Worksheet
    
    Set shtS = Worksheets("Time Storage")
    
    If Intersect(Target, Range("B4:B12")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    lngR = shtS.Cells(shtS.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    If shtS.Cells(lngR, "A").End(xlUp).Value <> Date Then
        lngR = shtS.Cells(shtS.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        shtS.Cells(lngR, "A").Value = Date
    End If
    
    For Each rngC In Intersect(Target, Range("B4:B12"))
        If rngC.Value <> "" Then
           shtS.Cells(lngR, rngC.Row - 2).Value = Target.Value
       End If
    Next rngC
    
End Sub
```

(I enter timestamps into cells "B4:B12" of a sheet named "Time Entry", and I  store them into columns B through M of a sheet named "Time Storage".

**Problem is**: the data in the "time storage" sheet doesn't seem to appear horizontally in one single row. Instead, it appears in a downward diagonal pattern.)

Edit: Sharing the screenshot:

#### "Time Entry" Sheet

[image: "Time Entry" Sheet]

#### "Time Sheet" Storage

[image: "Time Sheet" Storage]

Comment: you should add data sample of your sheets "Time Entry" and "Time Storage" - the desireds results (even make them manualy)

Comment: For what you are trying to achieve I would not use the `Worksheet_Change` event, but a Sub that is called by a Button or something else.

Comment: I see what you're saying. I guess the reason why Worksheet_Change event is used here is because we're trying to automate this (so that we would no longer need to click any buttons each time a timestamp is made). But i definitely see your point. i appreciate your feedback very much.

Comment: The thing is you can't run your code on a single Cell event, let's assume he writes a new data in `Range("B6")`, do you want to make a new record on "time storage" sheet ? then when he updates a value in "B7" what now ? the `Date` is already the same and you don;t update the record, see my point ?

Comment: I've thought about that as well. Although I figured, the new data (all the new changes) could probably be used as an audit trail (to be reflected on a separate sheet) so we could trace how many times the employee attempted to create a timestamp for each period (break, lunch, etc). And then we could create another sheet which only shows the final/last timestamp the employee entered for each period. Not sure if this is doable though.

Comment: Not see the big issue (maybe it is) to add a large Button on a Sheet with Caption **Submit**, this actualy makes the user confirm all his data his correct, than again this is your system and you know hoe reliable the users using it

Comment: I see your point. I'll see what i can do. Please know that i appreciate all of those stuff you pointed out. Thanks again sir/madam. Much appreciated.

Comment: Let me know if you want a working code with a Button or some other `Sub` that is called by the user

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to diagnose if you included a screenshot. I'm assuming every row in Time Storage still has a date in column A and the remaining columns are filled diagonally.

The code runs on the Worksheet_Change event, which means it runs every time any cell is changed. Each individual cell being changed is causing all of the code to run, adding a single extra line with only 1 value at a time.

You should really only want the code to run once at the end when the last cell is updated. Assuming you fill the cells in order, the code should only run once when the Target range intersects with B12. So this check:

```
If Intersect(Target, Range("B4:B12")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
```

should be:

```
If Intersect(Target, Range("B12")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
```

and then the loop should run through all cells. So the rngC should be declared as a Cell instead of a Range and the loop:

```
For Each rngC In Intersect(Target, Range("B4:B12"))
```

should actually be:

```
For Each rngC In Range("B4:B12")
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response sir. I edited my post and i included the screenshot of my sheets. The reason why it needs to run every time any cell is changed is because we need the timestamp data real time. Nevertheless, your post kind of pointed me to the right direction somehow and although i still haven't figured it out, i'll see what i can do. Thanks again. I appreciate your help very much.